# How do add a Percentage column to this Google Sheet pivot table

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have a pivot table, in Google Sheets, and want to add a percentage column.

EDIT: here is a link to a sample spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12qyhOtKphW1iBWAOtfDHU1RdZRZ_Nq91eQtdghZzIyc/edit?usp=sharing

Below you can see the pivot table with the column (E) that I've manually added next to it, showing what I want to achieve, but as part of the pivot table, which is a simple:

E4=D4/C4

[image]

However, I have tried adding a Calculated Field under Values but can't work out the right formula; this didn't work:

='Checked In'/'Events'

nor did:

=D4/C4

I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't for the life of me work it out. Can anyone shine a light on what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Can you share with us a sample copy of your spreadsheet so that we may further understand your current situation?

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer: Only use the column headers of the raw data and not the column headers of the other existing calculated fields.

`Note:` Since you have not shared a sample spreadsheet, I have made a sample data just to show the process.

### Sample Raw Data

[image: Sample Raw Data]

### Creating a Pivot Table

Select the desired data to be added to the table which only includes the useful column headers (like the one selected in the sample raw data image).

[image: Pivot Table]

### Add a Calculated Field

[image: Calculated Field]

To add a calculated field, look for the `Values` section in the `Pivot table editor` and click add (as shown above). To enter a formula, the pivot table editor requires you to use the `column headers` instead of the `cell range` (A1 notation). The formula you provided works just fine. In this case, I used `='Checked in'/Events` to check if column headers with one word do not necessarily need single quotation marks (which will result in the following):

[image: Output]

Note: Always use `'string'` (single quotation mark) format in using `column headers` especially when the column headers contain spaces (like `Checked in` in the example).

Note: You may change the Column Header `Output` just by selecting the cell and renaming it.

### Sample Modifications

You may also use other Google Sheets functions in the formula just like:
[image: ROUND UP]

Which results to:

[image: Round Up Table]

### Reference

- [Create & Use Pivot Tables](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900)

### Additional Info

When trying to add additional calculated fields using data based from other calculated fields, `always use the original column headers of the raw data and not the column headers of the calculated fields` as it returns an error just like the one below:

[image: error]

In your case, I modified your formula to

`=COUNTA('Venue Name')/COUNTUNIQUE('Event Date')`

Since both `Venue Name` and `Event Date` are the column headers of your raw data and not `Checked in` and `Events`. The current output of the corrected formula should look like this:

[image: corrected formula]

To address the decimals in the output values, you may refer to the `Sample Modifications` section of this answer.

Comment: If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you so much for the excellent and very thorough reply, it is much appreciated.

Unfortunately, it's not worked for me.

My apologies for not sharing a dummy sheet. I've now created one and added it to the description above, but here is the link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12qyhOtKphW1iBWAOtfDHU1RdZRZ_Nq91eQtdghZzIyc/edit?usp=sharing

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you for replying! Based from your pivot table, the column headers used in your formula would be invalid as these headers are already calculated fields. For now, you may try to use `=COUNTA('Venue Name')/COUNTUNIQUE('Event Date')` as it worked on my side. I will edit my answer later, but for now, `please take note that we should always use the column headers of the raw data and not the column headers of existing calculated fields`.

Comment: I have added an `Additional Info` section to my answer to address your actual issue. If you have any further questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)